# Difference between Internal Hash and External Hash

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

From the book 'Fundamentals of Database Systems':
**Internal Hash**

> For internal files, hashing is typically implemented as a hash table through the use
>   of an array of records. Suppose that the array index range is from 0 to M – 1, as
>   shown in Figure 17.8(a); then we have M slots whose addresses correspond to the
>   array indexes. We choose a hash function that transforms the hash field value into
>   an integer between 0 and M − 1. One common hash function is the h(K) = K mod
>   M function, which returns the remainder of an integer hash field value K after divi-
>   sion by M; this value is then used for the record address. [...]
>
> A collision occurs when the hash field value of a record that is being inserted hashes
>   to an address that already contains a different record.

**External Hash**

> Hashing for disk files is called external hashing. To suit the characteristics of disk
>   storage, the target address space is made of buckets, each of which holds multiple
>   records. A bucket is either one disk block or a cluster of contiguous disk blocks. The
>   hashing function maps a key into a relative bucket number, rather than assigning an
>   absolute block address to the bucket. A table maintained in the file header converts
>   the bucket number into the corresponding disk block address, as illustrated in
>   Figure 17.9.
>   The collision problem is less severe with buckets, because as many records as will fit
>   in a bucket can hash to the same bucket without causing problems.

I have the following question:
1) A record is always recorded inside a block, so does the internal hash return the block-address and the position of the record inside the block?
2) Why is the collision problem less severe with external hash? I mean, let's suppose that every block can store 10 records; I speculate that the file I will store contains 100 records, then, using external hash, I allocate maybe 11-12 buckets(I assume that a bucket=1 block), so the hash function will  return 10-12 address to the buckets. 
If I use an internal hash, because the hash function returns a direct address, I would use a functions that return to me about 100-120 addresses.
 So what's the difference? In this way I think I have the same probability of collision using the two methods.

Comment: Please, name the book. 1) The implementation may choose, or even perform secondary hashing 2) it seems to me your are right. I don't see the difference there.

Comment: I have added the book title. What do you mean with "The implementation may choose, or even perform secondary hashing"?

Comment: It was an answer to "A record is always recorded inside a block, so does the internal hash return the block-address and the position of the record inside the block?" The implementation of hashtable may choose to compute only block address and perform a linear search inside the block, or compute an address inside the block too.

Comment: If I understand clearly internal here means something in memory/RAM while external means something in disks/secondary storage.

Answer (score 1):

The internal hashing is an array that contains the address of the hash key. Therefore every array index can only contain one address of the hash key so if another hash key assigns to the same index of the array this will cause a collision. On the other hand, external hashing is mainly buckets of M. And every bucket can occupy more than one hash key. Therefore collision will happen when the bucket gets full.

Answer (score 0):

As much I have understood, you can look at 'external hashing' as 'open hashing'. In open hashing what we do is, each of the member in the hash table points to a unique list which can store multiple keys. Thus when collision occur, the keys are entered into the list pointed by the hash table element. This way the there is a less chance of collision( it depends upon the size of the list). I found this slide very useful, have a look (slide number 30 & 32)  - http://www.slideshare.net/gourab87/chapter13-8045092

Answer (score 0):

When the authors of the book consider internal hash files, they think about hashing defined on files in the **main memory**. They just consider assigning elements to an array when they elaborate on internal hashing. Moreover, they do not put records into blocks, when writing about internal hashing, and likely do not have an intention to compare these two types of hashing. Hashing which is of our interest for disk storage is external hashing. This should be an answer to both questions.